# having trouble in $.each loop passing variables from one ajax function to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to call ajax function in another function but as i have created a loop the same value gets passed again and again evertime the loop calls 
let me show you my code

```js
$(window).load(function(e) {
  // grab the scroll amount and the window height
  loadmore();
  select_likes();

  select_share();
  // get_recieve_friend_requests();
  // get_sent_friend_requests();
});

function loadmore() {
  var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
  // alert(lastID);

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url("user/get_all_post"); ?>',
    data: {
      id: lastID
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(data) {
      $('.load-more').show();
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);
      var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

      if (json == "") {
        $("#bottom").append('<div class="btn btn-default col-md-6" >' + 'No More Results' + '</div>');
        $("#Load_more_data").hide();
      } else {
        $postID = json[json.length - 1].id;
        $('.load-more').attr('lastID', $postID);
        $.each(json, function(key, data) {
          var post_id = data.id;
          var data_id = [data.length - 1].id;
          // alert(data_id);
          var post_status = data.status;
          var status_image = data.status_image;
          var multimage = data.multimage;
          var commentID = $('.comment-more').attr('commentID');
          
          // alert(comment_post_id);
          if (!post_status == "" && !status_image == "") {
            $("#status_data").append('<div class="col-md-6 postdata' + post_id + '"><a ><?php echo img($user_image); ?></a><a class="weshare_user_name text-font"><?php echo $uname; echo " "; echo $lname;?></a><div class="weshare_user_status">' + post_status + '</div><div class="weshare_user_singleimage"><img style="height:300px; width:400px;" src="<?php echo base_url('
              uploads '); ?>/' + status_image + '"></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><ul class="list-inline"><li><a onclick="like(' + post_id + ');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</a></li><li><a onclick="select_comment(' + post_id + ');"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comment</a></li><li><a onclick="share(' + post_id + ');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Share</a></li><button type="button" id="comment_show" onclick="select_comment(' + post_id + ');"><i class="fa fa-caret-down "></i></button></ul></div></div><div class="panel-footer " id="comment_div" onload="select_comment(' + post_id + ');"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><a href="#">13 people</a> like this</div></div><ul class="media-list"><li  class="media_comment"></li><li class="media"><div class="media-left media-top"><?php echo img($user_file_image); ?></div><div class="media-body"><div class="input-group"><form action="" id="form_content_image"><textarea name="textdata" id="content_comment_image" cols="25" rows="1"  class="form-control message"  placeholder="Whats on your mind ?"></textarea><button type="submit" id="comment_button_image" onclick="comment_here_image(' + post_id + ');">Comment</button></form></div></div></li></ul></div></div>');
          } else if (!post_status == "" && status_image == "") {
            $("#status_data").append('<div class="col-md-6 postdata' + post_id + '" ><a ><?php echo img($user_image); ?></a><a class="weshare_user_name text-font"><?php echo $uname; echo " "; echo $lname;?></a><div class="weshare_user_status">' + post_status + '</div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><ul class="list-inline"><li><a  onclick="like(' + post_id + ');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</a></li><li><a onclick="select_comment(' + post_id + ');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comment</a></li><li><a onclick="share(' + post_id + ');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Share</a></li><button type="button" id="comment_show" onclick="select_comment(' + post_id + ');" ><i class="fa fa-caret-down "></i></button></ul></div></div><div class="panel-footer "  id="comment_div" onload="select_comment(' + post_id + ');"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><a href="#">13 people</a> like this</div></div><ul class="media-list"><li   class="media_comment"></li><li class="media"><div class="media-left media-top"><?php echo img($user_file_image); ?></div><div class="media-body"><div class="input-group"><form action="" id="form_content"><textarea name="textdata" id="content_comment" cols="25" rows="1"  class="form-control message"  placeholder="Whats on your mind ?"></textarea><button type="button" id="comment_button" onclick="comment_here(' + post_id + ');" >Comment</button><?php echo form_close();?></div></div></li></ul></div></div>');
          } else if (!multimage == "") {
            $("#status_data").append('<div class="col-md-6 postdata' + post_id + '" ><a ><?php echo img($user_image); ?></a><a class="weshare_user_name text-font"><?php echo $uname; echo " "; echo $lname; ?></a><div class="weshare_user_multimage"><img style="height:300px; width:400px;" src="<?php echo base_url('
              uploads '); ?>/' + multimage + '"></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><ul class="list-inline"><li><a  onclick="like(' + post_id + ');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</a></li><li><a onclick="select_comment(' + post_id + ');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comment</a></li><li><a onclick="share(' + post_id + ');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Share</a></li><button type="button" id="comment_show" onclick="select_comment(' + post_id + ');"><i class="fa fa-caret-down "></i></button></ul></div></div><div class="panel-footer " id="comment_div" onload="select_comment(' + post_id + ');"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><a href="#">13 people</a> like this</div></div><ul class="media-list"><li  class="media_comment' + post_id + '"></li><li class="media"><div class="media-left media-top"><?php echo img($user_file_image); ?></div><div class="media-body"><div class="input-group"><form action="" id="form_content_multimage"><textarea name="textdata" id="content_comment_multimage" cols="25" rows="1"  class="form-control message"  placeholder="Whats on your mind ?"></textarea><button type="submit" id="comment_button_multimage" onclick="comment_here_multimage(' + post_id + ');" >Comment</button><?php echo form_close();?></div></div></li></ul></div></div>');
          } else {
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}

function select_comment(post_id) {
  // alert(post_id);
  var Post_id = post_id;
  var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url("user/select_comment"); ?>',
    data: {
      Post_id: Post_id,
      User_id: User_id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);
      var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

      $.each(json, function(key, data) {
        var comment = data.comment;
        var post_id = data.post_id;
        $post_id = post_id;
        // alert(comment);
        // alert(post_id);
        $("#comment_post_id").attr('value', $post_id);
        $(".media_comment").append('<li class=" media-top"><?php echo img($user_file_image); ?> <p>' + comment + '</p> <br><a href="#">Like</a> · <a href="#">Reply</a> </li>');
      });
    }
  });
}
}

function comment_here($post_id) {
  $(document).on('click', '#comment_button', function(e) {
    // this will prevent form and reload page on submit.
    e.preventDefault();

    // here you will get Post ID
    var Post_id = $post_id;
    var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
    var textdata = $('#content_comment').val();
    // alert(textdata);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo base_url("user/post_comment"); ?>',
      data: {
        Post_id: Post_id,
        User_id: User_id,
        textdata: textdata
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert('you have like this');
        var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);
        var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);
        $postID = json[json.length - 1].post_id;
        alert($postID);
        $('.comment-more').attr('commentID', $postID);
        jQuery('#form_content')[0].reset();

      }
    });
  });
}

function comment_here_image($post_id) {
  $(document).on('click', '#comment_button_image', function(e) {
    // this will prevent form and reload page on submit.
    e.preventDefault();

    // here you will get Post ID
    var Post_id = $post_id;
    var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
    var textdata = $('#content_comment_image').val();
    alert(textdata);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo base_url("user/post_comment"); ?>',
      data: {
        Post_id: Post_id,
        User_id: User_id,
        textdata: textdata
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert('you have like this');
        jQuery('#form_content_image')[0].reset();
        Post_id = "";

      }
    });
  });
}

function comment_here_multimage($post_id) {
  $(document).on('click', '#comment_button_multimage', function(e) {
    // this will prevent form and reload page on submit.
    e.preventDefault();

    // here you will get Post ID
    var Post_id = $post_id;
    var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
    var textdata = $('#content_comment_multimage').val();
    // alert(textdata);
    alert(Post_id);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo base_url("user/post_comment"); ?>',
      data: {
        Post_id: Post_id,
        User_id: User_id,
        textdata: textdata
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert('you have like this');
        jQuery('#form_content_multimage')[0].reset();
        Post_id = "";
      }
    });
  });
}
```

now what i am doing in this code is first on page load a function calls loadmore(); this loadmore contains all the post from my databse that are shown on my page by decreasing the id using json[json.length-1].id now i want to comment on those posts so i appended a textarea also in my code but when i click on the comment button that is comment_here(post_id) the post_id that is passing pass correctly  but everytime when i select a post and comment on it the id before that in the loop gets called first then the 'clicked' id calls so i neet to stop the loop and pass the id in decresing in the comment as well what i am doing wrong ? if there is something you dont understand do tell me.

Comment: Firstly, please format your code before adding it to the question. This was very difficult to read. Secondly you have several syntax issues which need addressing. Check the console to diagnose them

Comment: i have corrected the syntax but there was no  change in the output @RoryMcCrossan